# ASP.Net HTML Code Window Constant Name

Tags: asp.net, contextmenu, commandbar

I am trying to place a right-click menu addin for the asp.net html window.
The one I currently have works on the C#/Vb code window...just not in the html code window.

```
        commandBars = (CommandBars)applicationObject.CommandBars;
        codeCommandBar = commandBars["Code Window"];
```

That would get me the context menu (right-click menu) of the non-html code window.

But what constant name would get me the html code window context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ASPX Context" is the aspx code window right-click menu.

I found a way to enumerate the commandbars[] and list them all.. I just had to search for the right one.